# Writing a bit reader in JAVA (32-bit little-endian most-to-least-significant bit packing)

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, endianness

No matter how I toss and turn the bytes & bits, I just cannot get this to work. I understand endianess quite ok, and MSB (most significant bit) on some degree. But I'm not able to put the two together it seems.

Currently I have the data in an ordinary JAVA byte[] array. Symbols within the bit stream are encoded using 32-bit little-endian most-to-least-significant bit packing. And I need to read it in a kind of bit reader N bits a time like:

`public int read(int bits, boolean advanceReader)`

Of course keeping track of the

```
private int byteOffset;
private int bitOffset;
```

The issue is getting the values as integers, this I just can't comprehend how to achieve correctly :(

Edit: I'm trying with this Apache Licensed BitReader class with added little endian (I added on to the readInt()) support (original code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jcodec/jcodec/master/src/main/java/org/jcodec/common/io/BitReader.java):

```
public class BitReader {

protected int deficit;
protected int curInt;
private ByteBuffer bb;
private int initPos;

public BitReader(ByteBuffer bb) {
    this.bb = bb;
    initPos = bb.position();
    curInt = readInt();
    deficit = 0;
}

public final int readInt() {
    if (bb.remaining() >= 4) {
        deficit -= 32;
        final int b1 = bb.get() & 0xff;
        final int b2 = bb.get() & 0xff;
        final int b3 = bb.get() & 0xff;
        final int b4 = bb.get() & 0xff;
        if (bb.order() == ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN) {
            return (b1 << 24) | (b2 << 16) | (b3 << 8) | b4;
        } else {
            return (b4 << 24) | (b3 << 16) | (b2 << 8) | b1;
        }
    } else {
        return readIntSafe();
    }
}

public int readNBit(int n) {
    if (n > 32) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can not read more then 32 bit");
    }

    int nn = n;

    int ret = 0;
    if (n + deficit > 31) {
        ret |= (curInt >>> deficit);
        n -= 32 - deficit;
        ret <<= n;
        deficit = 32;
        curInt = readInt();
    }

    if (n != 0) {
        ret |= curInt >>> (32 - n);
        curInt <<= n;
        deficit += n;
    }

    // for(--nn; nn >=0; nn--)
    // System.out.print((ret >> nn) & 1);
    // System.out.println();

    return ret;
}

public int position() {
    return ((bb.position() - initPos - 4) << 3) + deficit;
}

}
```

Maybe I'm missing something in the readNBit, it still handles like big endian? The results are near there, but not quite correct.

Some data:

> The array:
>   [ 0]  byte    64
>   [ 1]  byte    1
>   [ 2]  byte    -32
>   [ 3]  byte    1
>   [ 4]  byte    100
>   [ 5]  byte    20
>   [ 6]  byte    30
>   [ 7]  byte    3
>   [ 8]  byte    47
>   [ 9]  byte    -91
>   [10]  byte    52
>   [11]  byte    -12
>   [12]  byte    2
>   [13]  byte    -6
>   [14]  byte    11
>   [15]  byte    -24
>   [16]  byte    41
>   [17]  byte    98
>   [18]  byte    -124
>   [19]  byte    52
>   Deficit = 21
>   Position (byte array) = 12

Reading 32 bits gets me: -1510145665

Should be apparently: -1510145696

```
byte[] array = {
  64, 1, -32, 1,
  100, 20, 30, 3,
  47, -91, 52, -12,
  2, -6, 11, -24,
  41, 98, -124, 52
};
ByteBuffer bArray = ByteBuffer.wrap(array);
bArray.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
BitReader bitReader = new BitReader(bArray);
bitReader.readNBit(32);
bitReader.readNBit(32);
bitReader.readNBit(21);
int luku = bitReader.readNBit(32);
```

Luku == -1510145665, and I think it should be -1510145696.

Comment: Have a look at `java.nio.ByteBuffer` and its byte-ordering capabilities.

Comment: Yes, that is easy, just putting the order. No problem there. Previously I tried to pass the array as ByteBuffer with the ordering set to the bit reader and advancing the reader per byte by reading the integer from the whole byte onwards in correct endianess. But still I was unable to extract the bits correctly.

Comment: Can you show us some code so we can see what your problem is?  Accessing bits is not so different to accessing bytes.

Comment: You don't need all this. You're keeping a dog and barking yourself. Just set the correct byte order into the `ByteBuffer` and then call `ByteBuffer.readInt()`. Two lines of code. Please supply some data that exhibits the ordering you describe, and its values when decoded correctly.

Comment: Indeed, I just kept the original bit play in the ReadInt in case it was somehow faster etc than the readInt() from buffer. Maybe there was a reason why the original author did what he did.

Comment: Here is some run time example:
The array ([index] value):
[12] byte 2 
[13] byte -6 
[14] byte 11 
[15] byte -24 
[16] byte 41 
[17] byte 98 
[18] byte -124 
[19] byte 52  
deficit = 21
position = 12

Reading 32 bits gets me: -1510145665
Should be apparently: -1510145696

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'm already doing: 
`ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
BitReader bitReader = new BitReader(buf);`

Comment: Near there. -1510145696 is the right answer (I think), and -1510145665 is what I get. {47, -91, 52, -12} kinda, deficit is 21 == bit position is 85.

Comment: Can you post the byte array in hex please, and the result.

Comment: Like this?
`const unsigned char array[20] =
{
    0x40, 0x01, 0xe0, 0x01,
    0x64, 0x14, 0x1e, 0x03,
    0x2f, 0xa5, 0x34, 0xf4,
    0x02, 0xfa, 0x0b, 0xe8,
    0x29, 0x62, 0x84, 0x34
};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
47, -91, 52, -12 to little endian int => 11110100001101001010010100101111
2, -6, 11, -24 to little endian int => 11101000000010111111101000000010
```

After consuming 21 bits, the following 32 bits `10100101111111010000000101111111` which is `0xA5FD017F` in hex and `2784821631` in decimal.

```
System.out.println(0xA5FD017F);
long l = 2784821631L;
System.out.println((int)l);
```

will both give you -1510145665. So the original code is correct.

Your changes to take the input byte array as little endian may not what you want when you are reading less than 32 bits at a time. You may have to read one byte at a time instead of using the existing readInt()

Comment: Thank you, I also now believe that this is the correct behavior. The problem actually seems to be in the check* methods: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jcodec/jcodec/master/src/main/java/org/jcodec/common/io/BitReader.java

They are supposed to read bits without advancing, but they don't correctly "reset" the progress when done in little endian.